# Wasn't Korach the star of the show?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, ekev

In Parshas Eikev (Devarim 11:6), Moshe recounts the results of the dispute between Korach and Moshe, namely the ground opening its mouth and swallowing them up.  There is one significant person missing from the list - Korach.  Doson and Aviram, who joined Korach, are mentioned, but Korach is left out.

Why is Korach, who initiated the whole confrontation, not mentioned as having been swallowed up?

The answer doesn't seem to be related to whether or not Korach was alive when he was swallowed up, as the above cited verse does not say anything about that group being swallowed up alive. The answer does not seem to be that Korach was not swallowed up, because Bamidbar 26:10 says (as understood by one opinion in Sanhedrin 110) that Korach was swallowed up.

Comment: @DoubleAA Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16500/discussion-between-yez-and-double-aa).

Comment: For a text critical approach to separating the stories of Korach from that of Doson and Aviram, see here: http://thetorah.com/korah-datan-and-abiram-case-study/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

רמב"ן

והזכיר לאשר עשה לדתן ולאבירם. ולא הזכיר קרח ועדתו שיצאה אש מלפני ה' ותאכל אותם, בעבור כי איש זר הקרב להקטיר קטורת הוא מלאוי התורה (במדבר יז ה), ו לעולם הוא נענש לדורות כאשר קרה גם לעזיהו(דה"י ב כו יט), על כן לא מניו האותות המדבר.

I understand it as saying that since he and his congregation brought ketoros and he's not a kohen, so he's anyway meant to be punished for generations (like Uziyahu), so it's not counted in the wonders/signs that Hashem did in the desert.